# How to retrieve string using XPath without returning null errors

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

I'm trying to write "Private Equity Group; USA" to a file.

"Private Equity Group" prints fine, but I get an error for the "USA" portion

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'style.display')"
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="cl profile-xsmall">
  <div class="cl profile-small-bold">Private Equity Group</div>
  USA
</div>
```

The XPath for "USA" is:

```
//*[@id="addrDiv-Id"]/div/div[3]/text()
```

I get the error when I print the XPath or have it in an `if` statement:

```
if (internet.has_xpath?('//*[@id="addrDiv-Id"]/div/div[3]/text()')){
    file.puts "#{internet.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="addrDiv-Id"]/div/div[3]/text()')}"
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Capybara or poltergeist? Show your code.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole: Thanks for the response. My apologies for being unclear and using a poor format. Hopefully these edits will help

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 1):

Capybara is not a general purpose xpath library - it is a library aimed at testing, and therefore is element centric.  The xpaths used need to refer to elements, not text nodes.

```
if (internet.has_xpath?('//*[@id="addrDiv-Id"]/div/div[3]')){
  file.puts internet.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="addrDiv-Id"]/div/div[3]').text
}
```

although using XPath at all for this is just a bad idea. Whenever possible default to CSS, it's easier to read, and faster for the browser to process - something like

```
if (internet.has_css?('#addrDiv-Id > div > div:nth-of-type(3)')){
  file.puts internet.find('#addrDiv-Id" > div > div:nth-of-type(3)').text
}
```

or if the HTML allows it (I don't know without seeing more of the HTML)

```
if (internet.has_css?('#addrDiv-id .cl.profile-xsmall')){
  file.puts internet.find('#addrDiv-id .cl.profile-xsmall').text
}
```

or even cleaner if it works for your use case

```
file.puts internet.first('#addrDiv-id .cl.profile-xsmall')&.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it :

```
xml = %{<div class="cl profile-xsmall">
<div class="cl profile-small-bold">Private Equity Group</div>
USA</div>}

require 'rexml/document'
doc = REXML::Document.new xml
print(REXML::XPath.match(doc, 'normalize-space(string(//div[@class="cl profile-xsmall"]))'))
```

Output :

```
["Private Equity Group USA"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd say the HTML isn't well-formed, using `span` would have been better, but this works:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="cl profile-xsmall">
  <div class="cl profile-small-bold">Private Equity Group</div>
  USA
</div>
EOT

div = doc.at('.profile-small-bold')

[div.text.strip, div.next_sibling.text.strip].join(' ')
# => "Private Equity Group USA"
```

which can be reduced to:

```
[div, div.next_sibling].map { |n| n.text.strip }.join(' ')
# => "Private Equity Group USA"
```

The problem is that you have two nested divs, with "USA" trailing, so it's important to point to the inner node which has the main text you want. Then "USA" is in the following text node, which is accessible using [`next_sibling`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#next_sibling-instance_method):

```
div.next_sibling.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Text
div.next_sibling # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3c "\n  USA\n">
```

Note, I'm using CSS selectors; They're easier to read, which is echoed by the Nokogiri documentation. I have no proof they're faster, and, because Nokogiri uses libxml to process both, there's probably no real difference worth worrying about, so use whatever makes more sense, and run benchmarks if you're curious.

You might be tempted to use `text` against the `div class="cl profile-xsmall"` node, but don't be sucked into that, as it's a trap:

```
doc.at('.profile-xsmall').text # => "\n  Private Equity Group\n  USA\n"
doc.at('.profile-xsmall').text.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip # => "Private Equity Group USA"
```

`text` will return a string of the text nodes after they're concatenated together. In this particular, *rare* case, it results in a somewhat usable result, however, usually you'll get something like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div><p>foo</p><p>bar</p></div>')
doc.at('div').text # => "foobar"
doc.search('p').text # => "foobar"
```

Once those text nodes have been concatenated it's *really* difficult to take them apart again. [Nokogiri's documentation](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#inner_text-instance_method) talks about this:

> Note: This joins the text of all Node objects in the NodeSet:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<xml><a><d>foo</d><d>bar</d></a></xml>')
doc.css('d').text # => "foobar"
```

> Instead, if you want to return the text of all nodes in the NodeSet:

```
doc.css('d').map(&:text) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

---

> The XPath for "USA" is:

```
//*[@id="addrDiv-Id"]/div/div[3]/text()
```

Um, no, not according to the HTML you gave us. But, let's pretend.

Using an absolute path to a node is a good way to write fragile selectors. It takes only a small change in the HTML to break your access to the node. Instead, find way-points to skip through the HTML to find the node you want, taking advantage of CSS and XPath to search downward through the DOM.

Typically, a selector like yours is generated by a browser, which isn't a good source to trust. Often browsers do fixups on malformed HTML, which changes it from what Nokogiri or a parser would see, resulting in a non-existing target, or the browser presents the HTML after JavaScript has had a change to run, which can move nodes, hide them, add new ones, etc.

Instead of trusting the browser, use `curl`, `wget` or `nokogiri` at the command-line to dump the file and look at it using a text editor. Then you'll be seeing it just as Nokogiri sees it, prior to any fixups or mangling.